# What is 4-pin onboard HDD power connector on Supermicro?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply

I'm running server using Supermicro X10SDV-4F-TLN2F motherboard. But I found unusual 4-pin male molex power connector soldered into mobo and User's manual says this connector is HDD PWR, and exsisting for power the "onboard HDD".

> 4-pin Power Connector for HDD use (To provide power from the motherboard to onboard HDD devices)

But I still can't get the point of this. Why HDD Power connector located on mobo? Does "onboard HDD" meaning any HDD installed inside server or something else?

Do I have to connect power cable from PSU to this connector even if I use SSD only? How can I use this?

This is the diagram of motherboard captured from user's manual. (As marked, J6 is the connector):

[image]

Here is the the [full user's manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/D/MNL-1726.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It's a mini-itx system, designed to be shoehorned into a case. The psu may have a minimal number of power cables for peripherals, so why not have a molex plug on the mb? It's very little cost. You can use it with any peripheral that requires it, including but not limited to, ssd's. You're over thinking this.

Answer (score 0):

In [the X10SDV-4F-TLN2F manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/D/MNL-1726.pdf) in chapter 2,  page 6, it is described as power for hard drives, connector J6:

> **2-6 Connecting Cables**
>
> This section provides brief descriptions and pin-out definitions for onboard headersand connectors. Be sure to use the correct cable for each header or connector.
>
> ATX PWR, DC PWR and HDD PWR Connectors (JPW1, PJ1, J6)
>
> The 24-pin ATX power connector at JPW1 is used to provide power to the motherboard. PJ1 is the 12V DC power connector that provides alternative power for special enclosure when the 24-pin ATX power is not in use. The 4-pin HDD power connector J6 provides power to onboard HDD devices.

Answer (score 0):

It may be designed for SATA DOM Power Connectors.

look at this link below：
https://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/SATADOM.cfm

> The Supermicro SuperDOM operates up to 2x faster than other SATA DOM products in the industry. Due to its optimized design the Supermicro SuperDOM does not require a 5V power cable as do other SATA DOM products on the market, thus improving performance and reliability. However, it is still backward compatible with server boards **requiring this 5V power cable**. The Supermicro SuperDOM is available in 128GB, 64GB, 32GB, and 16GB capacities and supports all Supermicro SuperServer® products and solutions.

Comment: Hello, welcome.  Link-only answers are not acceptable here.  You could improve your answer by editing it and adding some relevant stuff and then referring to the link for more details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175261)